# WPF DataGrid Column Changed Event. How to Detect Column Resizing?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, horizontal-scrolling

I have a problem with the default behavior of the resizing of columns:

If a DataGrid is too wide for its container, the horizontal scrollbar appears.
If I drag the bar to the right and resize most right column, the scrollbar sticks to the right.

In my case I don't want that behavior.
The scrollbar should either just not stick to the right,
or, perfect would be, a resize preview like MS Excel.

Can someone tell me how to achieve that?

Edit1:
This behavior is fine (not sticking to the right):
[image: Regular scrollbar behavior]

What I don't like is this:
[image: Stick/snap to the right]

If I could realize that easily, I would prefer:
[image: Excel behavior]

/Edit1

I am using .Net 4.8 for a simple WPF application.

If an example is need, the following will display two grids and the left one can be used for that behavior:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MasterViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <DockPanel>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Command="{Binding DisplaySelectionCountCommand}">Display Selection Count</Button>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            
            <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                 SelectionMode="Extended" local:MultiSelect.IsEnabled="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="100"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="100"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="100"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <DataGrid Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                  SelectionMode="Extended" local:MultiSelect.IsEnabled="True"/>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: If you know that you have many columns you should enable the horizontal scroll bar explicitly to improve the rendering perfomance. Your desired behavior is not clear. In case you want to keep the left hand column of the resizing column in the view, you can easily listen to the SizeChanged event of the DataGrid. Then in the event handler get the previous column and scroll it into view.

Comment: Maybe it is more clear like that:
The behavior of the scrollbar changes after it reaches the right end and I start resizing.
The scrollbar then sticks to the right. So if I resize the last column, I could easily lose the view of the other columns because of that.
Maybe I should add pictures to show what I mean.

Anyway, I don't want that change of behavior.

Comment: @BionicCode I tried to listen to that event, but it is only firing once on opening of the window, not at the start or during or after resizing a column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I suggested to listen to the `SizeChanged` event I didn't mean the `DataGrid` to be the source.

Since you are interested in the columns, you must listen to the cell event of course:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
      <EventSetter Event="SizeChanged" Handler="DataGridCell_SizeChanged" />
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void DataGridCell_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
  => (sender as DataGridCell).BringIntoView();
```

---

This is an alternative version that shows how to gain more control over the scroll position using the `ScrollViewer` of the `DataGrid`:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" 
          ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="DataGrid_ScrollChanged">
  <DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
      <EventSetter Event="SizeChanged" Handler="DataGridCell_SizeChanged" />
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private double OriginalScrollPosition { get; set; }
private bool IsResizingColumn { get; set; }

private void DataGrid_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
  if (this.IsResizingColumn 
    && TryFindVisualChildElement(dataGrid, out ScrollViewer scrollViewer))
  {
    this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
    {
      scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(this.OriginalScrollPosition);
      this.IsResizingColumn = false;
    }, DispatcherPriority.Background);
  }
}

private void DataGrid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var dataGridCell = sender as DataGridCell;
  if (TryFindVisualChildElement(this.DataGrid, out ScrollViewer scrollViewer))
  {
    this.OriginalScrollPosition = scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset;
    this.IsResizingColumn = true;
  }
}

private bool TryFindVisualChildElement<TChild>(DependencyObject parent, out TChild resultElement)
  where TChild : DependencyObject
{
  resultElement = null;

  if (parent is Popup popup)
  {
    parent = popup.Child;
    if (parent == null)
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  for (var childIndex = 0; childIndex < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); childIndex++)
  {
    DependencyObject childElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, childIndex);

    if (childElement is TChild child)
    {
      resultElement = child;
      return true;
    }

    if (TryFindVisualChildElement(childElement, out resultElement))
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Ah, okay, I misunderstood that.
Thanks for the suggestion.
I tested your it and have to say it "only" improves the behavior a little.
For the first columns, it stops the scrollbar if the resizing column would get out of view.
Since the last column will never get out of view, it will be the same.
And I would wish the scrollbar to never move right by its own.

Comment: Can't understand input *"only improves the behavior a little"* - not enough information. This example is meant to show you how you can react to the changing column size. It's the simplest approach to keep the resizing column insinde the view. You can fine tune the behavior for example if the scroll position is not optimal for you e.g. by adjusting the scroll position to compensate element Padding and Margin. Instead of calling BringIntoView() you can extract the ScrollViewer to gain full controll over the scrolling behavior and scroll manually to a calculated position.

Comment: @Luy I have added a quick second solution tha shows you how to use the ScrollViewer in order to keep the column/current view in place. It's more accurate than using BringIntoView(). It should fix any issues introduced by the very raw positioning behavior of the BringIntoView method.

Comment: Okay, the addition really was the thing I was searching for. Only had to change the little type-o "VerticalOffset" to "HorizontalOffset".

Thanks a lot, marked as answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have fixed it.